# EXCEL: change the color of a cell at a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I made a simple project on Excel about payments, I have to change the color of one cell if the payment has been done.
For example:

```
PAYMENT - PAID - ||||||||||||||||||||| - REMAINED

10.000$ - 5.000$ - "RED CELL" - 5.000$ remained

12.000$ - 12.000$ - "GREEN" - Paid
```

Sorry if it's not that clear, not easy to explain :)
I have no idea where to start.

Thanks to everyone will help!

Comment: Look into conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**I'm assuming that you have values in cells `A2:D6`.**

**How it works:**

- Select `C2:D6`.
- From *Home TAB* Click *Conditional Formatting*.
- Click *New Rule* then Select *Use formula to determine which Cells to
  format.*
- Write this formula: `=$C2>0`, Click *Format* & apply Red color to Font  &
  finish with Ok.
- Again reach to *New Rule* & write this formula: `=$C2=0`then apply
  Green color to Font & finish with Ok.

**Note,** *adjust cell references for formatting and in formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you #Kenneth,, keep asking ☺